# dataTransfer.setData does't set a file to list in Safari 9

Tags: javascript, html, safari, drag-and-drop

My ondragstart handler is:

```
function onDragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", "myText");
};
```

In Chrome it adds a `DataTransferItem` to `items` property of dataTransfer, but `files` property is empty. However drag and drop works fine in Chrome.

In Safari 9 dataTransfer has no `items` property and `files` property also is empty after setData. So, drag and drop doesn't work in Safari 9. How to fix?